Algorithm to determine closedness of orbits?
Consider a reductive group $G$ acting on an affine variety $X$. It is known that for every $x\in X$, we have $G.x\subseteq\overline{G.x}$ is open dense. Then $\partial({G.x})\subseteq X$ is a closed subvariety. We have
$$\partial(G.x)=\emptyset\iff G.x \text{ is closed}. $$
I want to know how can I get the ideal cutting out $\partial({G.x})$, giving the action $G\curvearrowright X$ and $x\in X$.
I expect an algorithm that I can program for easy examples. I have read the algorithm calculating ring of invariants, involving finding Gröbner bases of ideals. It would be great if anyone knows a similar algorithm.
The motivation is finding polystable points for the $G$-action.
